# How to remove div tag from html editor contents in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, regex

I am working on an application. In this application I have to insert News detail into Sql Databse.For entering Article i have used a Html editor.My code is:-

```
objNews.Article = Server.HtmlEncode(Regex.Replace(ckedi.Content.Trim().ToString(), "</?(div|DIV).*?>", ""));
```

I have used regex.Replace to remove tag from the string in html editor.When i enter div tag into the html editor then it removes div tag but it also remove other tag also.as ex: If i enter Text as:

```
<p><div width="200px;"> Sachin Retires from Cricket.</div></p>
```

then it stores text as

```
p> Sachin Retires from Cricket./p>
```

This regex removes p tag also.I want to remove div tag only not p tag.Please help me.

Comment: No it doesn't. [Your regex already does what you're after on the string you supplied.](http://glot.io/csharp/441557d6d5f18e38f1bacd398c360d1c) Did you even try it?

Comment: yes i did but it remove div tag and it also removes p tag also.I want to remove div tag only

Comment: Actually it does not removes the <p> tag completely but converts it to p>

Comment: It does not touch the `<p>` tag. Click the link I provided in my first comment.

Comment: Yes sir your link doing well.Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(?i)</?div[^>]*>
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

try this once

```
string divTag = "div";
            objNews.Article = Server.HtmlEncode(Regex.Replace(ckedi.Content.Trim().ToString(), "(</?)" + divTag + @"((?:\s+.*?)?>)", ""));
```